# how delete a file completely from a Windows System

Tags: c#, c++, c, operating-system

I have tried to search but I didn't found any good answer to my query.

I wanted to know how to delete a file completely from a Windows System, so that it cannot be recovered in any way.

I know there are some software's available on the internet which delete the files completely from a system. I wanted to do a small demonstration for myself and wanted to see if it was really deleted/erased from the system.

For example: If I delete a file by using SHIFT + DELETE, I know a normal user cannot recover that file. But there are recovery softwaress which can be used to recover that file. So, I just wanted to delete the file in a way so that recovery software cannot recover a particular file.

Can anyone please tell me, how this can be done? I would really appreciate. If someone can share a small piece of code that does that. I can understand it better in that fashion.

Thanks

With Regards

Comment: zero out the file and then shift delete

Comment: @Milind Just to be safe, fill up the rest of the hard drive with zeroes as well to be sure.

Comment: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Data_erasure

Comment: just out of curiosity why are you wanting to make this unavailable from recovery software..? are you perhaps doing something `Shady` or `Illegal` where as you feel you need to `CYA`..? can you provide more information as to the importance of this..?

Comment: Well, there's this http://superuser.com/q/86824/29943 but I don't think those answers are even correct.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your replies. I really found them useful. And methodman, when i am not doing anything illegal. I am just writing a secure chat program where i'll be using file sharing as well, which i will need to delete, so i asked. I don't think there is anything illegal in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a tough one and not answerable by "a small piece of code".

Assuming you have a super secret/embarassing/illegal/whatever file you really want to get rid of. First thing is, it should have been encrypted in the first place. Just saying.

Anyway, parts or even the whole of your file can show up in a lot of places. Memory, page file, hibernate file, supposedly empty spaces on your hard drive (for example after a relocation of the file content through defragmentation). Do you have an online synchronization service? Backups? A SSD drive that spreads your file all over the physcal blocks place at every write? O dear.

So to really really get rid of that file at least on your lokal system as a minimum measure you would have to

- Delete it through your API of choice (except through the normal UI which just moves it to the "trashcan")
- Disable and remove the system page file
- Remove the hibernate file
- Overwrite all supposedly empty spaces of the hard drive with random bytes
- Reboot the system
- Reinstantiate the page file

But: SSDs and some hard drives have spare capacity blocks that they use as fallback when blocks produce errors. If your file happened to be in such a failed block it might have silently been relocated by the drives firmware and the drive will never write that block again by means reachable through the Windows API. So if you want to be really sure you have to physically destroy all drives the file has ever been written to.

Comment: Great summary of why selectively deleting single files isn't possible.  I wish the related questions on SuperUser (where this is actually on topic) had answers as straightforward and well-informed.

Comment: Yeah, really great summary. It really helped me understand the concept. I am writing a secure chat program where i'll be making file sharing module as well, in which i will need to delete the file which was shared. So, i was confused but this really helped me understand things. If you would like to give me, any recommendations for my program, you are welcome :)

Comment: @AmanThakur: Try overwriting the complete file content with random bytes, close it, then delete it. As mentioned above there are still chances that the content is recoverable, but at least it won't be very easy to recover. And if you use cryptography in your program, don't try to write it yourself. Crypto is *hard*, even battle hardened experts get it wrong all the time. Search for well established and maintained crypto libraries that solve your particular problem.

Comment: Thanks Toni, you really gave me a very useful info. I really appreciate it.